# Why and how can a page be loaded normally while returning 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, header, http-status-code-403

This page returns 403 but at the same time renders html and load normally. Page: http://maldiveclub.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some server side JavaScript file looks like it's not accessible

```
GET http://maldiveclub.com/ [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 2619ms]

Call Stack:
onReload/<     resource://devtools/server/actors/webbrowser.js:1609:7

exports.makeInfallible/<     resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:101:14
```

Also, I'm loading over 14 megabytes in over 300 requests just to see 1 page. This really destroys performance: it's taking over 15 seconds just to load all the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /custom-403.html
```

This will return status `403` while showing content from `/custom-403.html`.